# Запуск приложения из JARа и манифест

Tags: maven, jar, java

Доброго всем времени суток! есть небольшая проблемка. создаю я appframework application под maven. в помке прописываю плагин для сборки в jar:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>

<configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>com.international.mainclass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>

  </plugin>
```

потом запускаю жарку и мне пишет ошибку : can't find main-class com.international.mainclass. в что я не так делаю?

Comment: добавляли <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix> ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли написать главный класс, только и всего.

Вы либо вовсе его не написали, либо вы не указали его тут вместо com.international.mainclass.

**UPD**

А какая разница? В итоге у вас класс-форма и вы её содаёте и показываете обычным образом. Либо у вас main прямо внутри класса-фаормы.

Comment: смотрю вы, cy6ergnom, пошутить любите. зачем что то писать не по делу???

Comment: Класс у меня написан, и указано все верно.

Comment: Так посмотрите внутрь JARа: что там, есть ли там вообще ваши классы? Положен ли туда манифест с правильно указанным классом?

Comment: Если я ручками с нуля пишу приложение, то все работает. Проблема возникает тогда, когда в нетбинсе формы создаются через графический интерфейс.

Comment: В жарке все есть, и манифест с указаным классом и класспаз, и сами *.class

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Раз класс не найден, то значит вы либо неверно его вписали, либо класс лежит не там, где должен. Приведите структуру каталогов jar'а и содержимое файла манифеста.