# Прописать Main класс в манифесте при сборке Mavenом

Tags: maven, java

Вобщем САБЖ. Собрал Mavenом jar'ник. В нем есть единственный класс с `static void main()`. Вроде при запуске `java -jar myjar jvm` сама должна находить класс с main и запускать его, но вот че то не хочет. Пишет - определите main class в манифесте. И я вот не знаю как это мавеном сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Запуск приложения из JARа и манифест](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35507/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-jar%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82), ответ в вопросе :). Только укажите версию плагина в maven, так более надежно.